# what is the replacement for ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator in Spring 5.x?

Tags: spring

We are planning to upgrade to spring 5.x.  In Spring 5.x  release ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator , BeanFactoryLocator, and BeanFactoryReference are removed.

what are the suggested alternatives to get application context?

Answer (score 2):

See [Removed Package, classes and methods](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#removed-packages-classes-and-methods) in the Spring 5 migration guide.

> Including SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor for EJB3 which was based on such a statically shared context. Preferably integrate a Spring backend via CDI instead.

So use CDI and probably a [CDI bridge](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DeltaSpike/Spring+CDI+integration) to do so, or even better create an architecture where you don't need this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for answer still -
You can implement ApplicationContextAware.

```
public class MyContextLocator implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("Inside setApplicationContext");
        applicationContext = context;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

This will give you access to already created Context in which this bean(MyContextLocator ) exists. Then you just call static 'getApplicationContext' for access to ApplicationContext